# Update the parent data when user navigates to a specific route path

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-cli

I'm new in VueJs, trying to set up a web application with Vue-route, and want to update the `<header>` style when user navigates to a specific URL, whether using "URL bar" directly or "navigation bar". In this case, we have a parent component that contains `height_status` data and some `<router-links>` on template.

I've done the "navigation bar" part with `$emit` technique and it works well but then I've tried to use it on `created` lifecycle hook in order to update the header whenever the `/home` route is created but event listener will not reach the parent_component.
How can I solve this? Is there a better way to do that?
Please see the code below:

### Parent_component.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <router-link to="/home" @height_size_ctrl="change_height">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">About us</router-link>
    <router-link to="/contact">Contact us</router-link>

    <header :class="height_status ? 'head-h-s' : 'head-h-m'"></header>

    <router-view/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Parent_component"
  },
  data() {
    return {
      height_status: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change_height(h) {
      this.height_status = h
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

### router.js

```
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: about
    },
    {
      path: '/contact',
      name: 'contact',
      component: contact
    }
  ]
})
```

---

### home.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>hello</h1>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'home',
  created: function(){
    return this.$emit("height_size_ctrl", true)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also change the router:

**router.js**

```
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      headerClass: 'head-h-s'
    }
  }
```

In your component

**Parent_component.vue**

```
computed: {
  headerClass() {
    return this.$route.meta.headerClass
  }
}
```

Now headerClass is available in the template.

```
<header :class="headerClass"></header>
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try class binding on `route` or `route name` something like:

```
<div :class="{'height_status': this.$route == '/home'}">Header</div>
```

or

```
<div :class="{'height_status': this.$route.name == 'Home'}">Header</div>
```

Comment: Good idea, class binding is the right answer but this condition is not working for me because there is class names as `head-h-s` and `head-h-m`. also `this.$route` could be something like `this.$route.path`, depends on the conditions. so I edited your answer to match the question. Thanks @kcsujeet

Answer (score 0):

As @kcsujeet said, class binding is the good way we can do this. In this case we need to look at the condition `this.$route.path`. if value is equal to the `/home` select `'head-h-m`, otherwise select `.head-h-s`.

```
<header class="head-sec" :class=" this.$route.path == '/home' ? 'head-h-m' : 'head-h-s'">
```

Also we're able to access other `route` defined properties using `this.$route`. I suggest take a look at the `router.js` file.

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    }
```